# Building an Expression with an anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, predicatebuilder

Let's say I've created some anonymous type via a LINQ query:

```
var query = from Person in db.People
            join Pet in Pets on Person.ID equals Pet.PersonID
            join Thingy in Thingies on Person.ID equals Thingy.PersonID
            select new { 
                Person.ID, 
                PetName = Pet.Name,
                Thing = Thingy.Thing,
                OtherThing = Thingy.OtherThing
            };
```

Now I want to apply some complex expressions to the query by dynamically building a predicate. What I have been doing for known types is something like this:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MyType>();
predicate = predicate.Or(myType => myType.Flag);
if (someCondition) {
    var subPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<MyType>();
    subPredicate = subPredicate.And(myType => myType.Thing == someThing);
    subPredicate = subPredicate.And(myType => myType.OtherThing == someOtherThing);
    predicate = predicate.Or(subPredicate);
}
query = query.Where(predicate);
```

Is it possible to do something similar with an anonymous type? I haven't found a way of using anonymous types with `PredicateBuilder` and I'm not familiar with any other constructs which would let me dynamically build an expression like this. If not, is there another approach I should take when dynamically generating nested expressions for a query?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would indend to apply your predicate in this case; the anonymous type *only has* an `ID` and `PetName` - what are `Thing` and `OtherThing` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Sorry, it's just some example code. The properties aren't important. It's just that I have an anonymous type which I want to use with `PredicateBuilder`. The real case involves comparing a number of properties against some filter pre-sets and extracting additional data from the database to further limit the results. I edited the original query to produce all of the correct properties for the example.

Comment: I would suggest upgrading to the latest LINQKit that doesn't need `.True` or `.False` any more. It is on GitHub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that all you need is `PredicateBuilder.False<T>` and `PredicateBuilder.True<T>` for an anonymous type, you can do it like this:

```
private static Expression<Func<T,bool>> MakeTrue<T>(IQueryable<T> ignored) {
    return PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
}
private static Expression<Func<T,bool>> MakeFalse<T>(IQueryable<T> ignored) {
    return PredicateBuilder.False<T>();
}
```

Now you can rewrite your code without the need to use the anonymous type explicitly:

```
var predicate = MakeFalse(query);
predicate = predicate.Or(v => v.ID > 10000);
query = query.Where(predicate);
```

The idea is to have the compiler do the type inference for you. Unfortunately, you end up with an unused method parameter.

Comment: I like to use the underscore variable for ignored parameters. Fortunately in the latest LINQKit you don't need to use `.True` and `.False` at all.

Comment: That works thanks! And this works with LINQKit's PredicateBuilder.New<T>() too. I thought maybe @NetMage had a way to initialize ExpressionStarter without this round about method.

Answer (score 4):

In the general case, it may be awkward to use `PredicateBuilder` here; it may be easier to use the `Expression` API directly. You'll need to get the `Type` representing the anonymous type, build the expression *without* a `T`, then flip into generic code to build the final lambda. Fortunately, not too tricky:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(GetQueryType(query));
var body = Expression.And(
    Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(p, "ID"), Expression.Constant(123)),
    Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(p, "PetName"), Expression.Constant("Jim"))
);

var filtered = ApplyPredicate(query, body, p);
```

with:

```
private static Type GetQueryType<T>(IQueryable<T> query) => typeof(T);
private static IQueryable<T> ApplyPredicate<T>(IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression body, params ParameterExpression[] parameters)
    => query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameters));
```

Additional: if you don't like the string literals for the member names:

```
var example = Example(query);
var p = Expression.Parameter(GetQueryType(query));
var body = Expression.And(
    Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(p, nameof(example.ID)),
        Expression.Constant(123)),
    Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(p, nameof(example.PetName)),
        Expression.Constant("Jim"))
);
```

with:

```
private static T Example<T>(IQueryable<T> query) => default(T);
```

Comment: Interesting and versatile approach. This does break out of static typing at compile time though, right? So if I typoed `Expression.PropertyOrField(p, "ID")` and wrote `Expression.PropertyOrField(p, "Id")` it would be a run-time error, correct?

Comment: @MikeC unfortunately yes, there's no easy way to get the name there - *unless* you do: `var example = Example(query);`, and use `nameof(example.ID)` and `nameof(example.PetName)`, where `Example` is: `private static T Example<T>(IQueryable<T> query) => default(T);` (added to answer)